# Program stops working - graphics.h

Tags: c++, windows, graphics, bgi

I have created a program which draws a rectangle , but as soon as it is initiated, a window pops up and says: "Unfortunately, the program has stoped". Why does this happen? What can i do to fix it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <graphics.h>

int main() {
initwindow(500, 300);
getch();
rectangle(200, 100, 200, 100);
closegraph();
}
```

Comment: I believe you are using a TurboC graphics library on what complier? MSVC, G++, Clang? It is not suggested, though. You may to manually do links to libraries (gdi32, bgi, and so).

Comment: I don't think you can use this old crap on anything but old Borland DOS compilers. You need access to the header and the BGI library both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are running old 16 bit **MS-DOS** app most likely on **Win7** or newer **OS** which is not a good idea (and on x64 bit will not even work anymore). Even if you are using 32bit compiler the **Borland BGI** is 16 bit. Another possibility of problem is wrong gfx **BGI-driver** which I do not see of initializing anywhere ( I am missing the use of `initgraph` but newer really used **BGI** so I could be wrong). So what to do:

1. check your code with some working example there are a lot of them here on **SO**
2. check **BGI** driver location (old **MS-DOS** supports `paths+filename` only up to `66` characters !!!)
3. try run your app in compatibility mode (**MS-DOS** or **W9x** or **XP**)
4. replace old 16bit Borland **BGI** with **WinBGI** emulator
5. run your App in **DOSBox** or any **MS-DOS** emulator

Answer (score 3):

You have not initiated the graphics engine by using InitGraph()

http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c-graphics-programming-tutorial

Just like OpenGL, Direct3D, SDL, etc. have an initialization function, BGI has InitGraph() which you must use, to even draw a simple dot!